# What is the effect on a personal pronoun due to a verb requiring a dative direct object?

Tags: verb, dative, pronoun, verb-usage, personal-pronoun

I recently came across a German sentence: -

> "Gefallen Ihnen die Rosen nicht?"

I know that **Gefallen is a Dativ verb**, but shouldn't the sentence be : -

> "Gefallen Sie die Rosen nicht?"

The rough translation of the above sentence (according to me) is: -

> "They did not like the roses?"

Since the subject in the sentence "They did not like the roses?" should be "They", It means that "They" should be in ***Nominativ Form*** and hence we should be using Nominativ Form of "They" i.e. ***"Sie"*** instead of ***"Ihnen"***.

But that is certainly not the case. What am I getting wrong?

Another sentence which I came across is: -

> "Ich helfe dir"

That is: -

> "I help you"

Now in this sentence, ***I*** is the **subject** (hence the Nominativ form) and ***helfe*** is the **Dativ verb** and ***dir*** is the **object** (Hence the Dativ Form).

So according to me, a personal pronoun should only take Dativ Form whenever it is an **"object"**.

Or have I got it all wrong? Maybe that is not how any of this works? Please do tell, when and where and how to convert a Personal pronoun in its Dativ form.

Comment: @DavidVogt: What is the purpose of linking a closed duplicate as duplicate source instead of the nonclosed question? If the linked one is good in itself, we need a reopen.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm The nonclosed question is about a different topic.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm, it is actually not a duplicate. That is why I voted for its reopening. If David Vogt had linking the putative original, this would be confusing, because that question is a totally different one.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich The proposed dupe doesn't have a good answer for this question though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, (1) It's good in my opinion. (2) It has 10 upvotes, which is a lot. (3) It was accepted, so the OP was happy. (4) There's no other, better answer. (5) Most importantly: A question being duplicate has nothing to do with the quality of answers, but with the similarity to another question.

Comment: Also: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27627/lieben-vs-gefallen

Comment: German "gefallen" works like Shakespeare's "like" not like "like" in current English. https://www.etymonline.com/word/like

Comment: Also note that the third person plural is used as a polite address here and should be translated as *you*, not *they*.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Compare my answer with the one at the proposed dupe, then think twice which actually answers the OP's question. And no, duplicates aren't about tge _similarity of questions_, but if they have an actual answer for a question, regardless of the question's similarity.

Comment: As addendum to Carsten S.' comment: you can tell that *Ihnen* means *to you* [polite address form] because it's capitalized. Normally, pronouns are written in lowercase.

Comment: @CarstenS OP is translating *Ihnen* as *they* because they expect nominative case, not because they do not understand what *Sie* means or what the relationship between *Sie* and *Ihnen* is.

Comment: @DavidVogt _"OP is translating Ihnen as they because they expect nominative case"_ Hard to tell without the OP jumping in to clarify. I think there are two misconceptions when trying to translate forth and back. _Ihnen_ in the original sentence clearly points out the polite address (it's capitalized), I am not so sure why the OP should try to translate to 3rd person plural if they really understood that difference. The 2nd misconception is _gefallen_ and _like_ vs. _please_ as in the dupe you proposed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The mistranslation is incidental. OP does not understand that *die Rosen* is the subject and *[iI]hnen* the dative object. Hence the desire to substitute a nominative for *[iI]hnen*.

Comment: @David Now we come closer. The dupe you proposed won't answer that well though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The mistake is exactly parallel, substituting nominative *du* for dative *dir* because the subject *der Film* is not recognised as such. And these are way too many comments for such a simple question that should have just been closed.

Comment: @DavidVogt "OP is translating *Ihnen* as *they* because they expect nominative case, not because they do not understand what *Sie* means […]": I'm not so sure about that given the questioner's statement "[...] Nominativ Form of 'They' i.e. 'Sie' instead of 'Ihnen' ". Because of this, I find it helpful to point out the mistranslation, even if incidental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an English speaker (like me) perhaps it's easiest to think of different translations for these verbs. For example think of *helfen* as meaning 'to give help' rather than 'to help'. Then *Ich helfe dir,* translates as "I give help to you," and the dative *dir* makes much more sense. Similarly, think of *gefallen* as meaning 'to please', or better 'to be pleasing (to someone)'. So *Die Rosen gefallen mir,* translates as 'The roses are pleasing to me' and again the dative seems more natural. (Unfortunately when you say it this way in English it sounds like you're a Bond villain; I didn't say it was a perfect system.)

Answer (score -1):

In your example, "*ich* helfe dir" you are being helped by *"I"*, so to speak.

Similarly, consider the sentence "Die Rosen gefallen *dir*." Here, the roses are pleasing "to you."

For your question, the word order is arranged to form a question.  However, "Ihnen" (the dative form of formal you) still translates to "to you."

Thus, the translation of "Gefallen Ihnen die Rosen" is "Are the roses pleasing to you."  "The Roses" is the subject.

"Gefallen Ihnen die Rosen nicht?" is the negation of this question.

"Gefallen Ihnen die Rosen nicht?" = "Aren't the roses pleasing to you?" (here "you" is formal)

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Please consider reformatting your answer. It is difficult to distingiush between your explanation and your english translation of the german parts. And it is `you are being helped by me`. From the content I'm not that sure how to describe which parts I miss in your answer.

Comment: @ Shegit Brahm  Feel free to reformat it as you please.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the thing with the `I`. So I did it a bit different - and am not fully sure about my minor corrections of comma and stuff. Most part I missed here to understand your intention. Please take a look at it, my English is far from fluent.

Comment: thanks, again what learned. I hope I keep it in mind. So this is the reason why you edited the quotation mark out? For me without the "?" it reads like it is incomplete with no reason. The content question I raised is that I have no real clue how to answer the question thus I just feel and cannot describe that it reads incomplete, that is all.

Answer (score -1):

> I recently came across a German sentence: -
>
> > "Gefallen Ihnen die Rosen nicht?"
>
> I know that Gefallen is a Dativ verb, but shouldn't the sentence be :
>
> > "Gefallen Sie die Rosen nicht?"

No, in this case *Ihnen* is the dative form of the polite address *Sie* (singular).

> The rough translation of the above sentence (according to me) is: -
>
> > "They did not like the roses?"

That's also misunderstood. The correct translation should be

> "The roses didn't please them?"

Note the english passive form *please* vs. the active form *like* as translation of *gefallen*. This is explained in more depth here: [Hat dir der Film gefallen? oder Hat du der Film gefallen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46559/hat-dir-der-film-gefallen-oder-hat-du-der-film-gefallen).

---

> Since the subject in the sentence "They did not like the roses?"
> should be "They", It means that "They" should be in **Nominativ Form** and
> hence we should be using Nominativ Form of "They" i.e. **"Sie"** instead
> of **"Ihnen"**.

*Sie* and *Ihnen* with the capital letter in the beginning is reserved for the polite address (always singular).
The 3rd person plural form is *sie* (nominative plural) and *ihnen* (dative plural).

---

> Or have I got it all wrong? Maybe that is not how any of this works?

The only thing you got wrong about these dative rules is, that German has a polite form of *you*, which is always singular. There's no equivalent in ([modern?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/is-thou-the-english-equivalent-of-sie)) English for that.

Also see: [How can a native English speaker know when it is appropriate to use the polite (Sie) or the familiar (Du)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/77/how-can-a-native-english-speaker-know-when-it-is-appropriate-to-use-the-polite).

Comment: This answer should have been given to the original question, now that you know that the current question is a duplicate.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich The proposed dupe question has nothing to do with the difference of _Du_ and _Sie_. Neither has [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36270/can-the-dative-be-put-in-the-start-of-the-sentence).